# what's the correct implementation of this multithreading program in C++(11)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a game program and it need to do large amount of AI calculation per frame,so I think it is a problem if I create hundreds of thread in every frame. Here is my solution(pseudo-code,for short,because the source code is too long):

```
void AIThread(AIAdapter *ai)
{
    while (!exit)
    {
        condition_variable.wait(goThink);

        // AI calculation...
        ai->Think();

        // notify the main thread
        mutex.lock();
        done++;
        mutex.unlock();
        condition_variable.notify(doneOne);
    }
}

// Invoke it per frame
void MainThread()
{
    condition_variable.notify(goThink);
    while(done<taskCount)
        condition_variable.wait(doneOne);

    Update();
}
```

And Here is the problem: when the last AIThread done,it notify the MainThread and break the while loop AND SOMETIME CONTINUE TO EXECUTE TO NEXT `condition_variable.notify(goThink);` . Now the last AIThread still stay in `if (!exit) goto Ready;` and DOES NOT RECEIVE the notification and stay at `condition_variable.wait(goThink);` forever. And the MainThread will stay at `while(done<taskCount)` forever.What should I do?How to write the correct code?

Comment: well, whatever it is I'm sure it doesn't have `goto`

Comment: well, let me rewrite it into while

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So, it seems like your intent is to block the main thread while the ai thread runs?  That seems rather counterproductive.

Comment: Yes the MainThread is blocked to wait for all results,but I have an independent UI thread. Or, what is the better solution?